# Finding the inverse of a matrix involving reciprocals of positive integers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The result of Example 16 suggests that perhaps the matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1  & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} \ \ \cdots \  & \frac{1}{n} \\ 
 \frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{3} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1}\\ \frac{1}{3} & . & \cdots & .\\. & . & \cdots & .\\\frac{1}{n}
 & \frac{1}{n+1} & \cdots & \frac{1}{2n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$

is invertible and $A^{-1}$ has integer entries. Can you prove that?

Comment: This is all you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix

Comment: Well its definately not a homework problem. Basically I'm trying to understand Linear Algebra on my own from the book by Hoffman and Kunje and found this problem left as an exercise.

Comment: @Grobber It is always helpful to say what you have tried. People are more likely to answer a question if it seems you have thought about it a bit, and also saying what you have tried helps them to direct their help.